# How many triangles can be formed from N points on a circle?

Tags: combinatorics, circles, triangles

I have a circle with N points on it, and I want to determine how many triangles can be formed using these points.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Andrew

Comment: The vertices of those triangles have to be from these $N$ points, right?

Comment: @PatrickLi Yes - that is right.

Comment: The question is unclear. What's the relevance of the points being on a circle ? Please show an example figure and pinpoint the triangles that should be counted.

Answer (score 9):

Each set of $3$ of the $N$ points determines a triangle, and each triangle is determined in this way, so all you have to do is determine how many $3$-element subsets a set of $N$ things has. If you don’t already know this, you should read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Comment: That's one way of interpreting the question. Another (more interesting, in my opinion) is to look at *all* triangles that can be generated by chords using $N$ points on a circle. For example, with $N=4$ points we have, essentially, divided the circle and its interior into 4 triangular regions, defined by a square and its two diagonals. For $N=5$ we'll have 11 possible triangles (look at $K_5$). If you allow overlapping triangles, you get an even larger number.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Answer would be NC3 which is nothing but N(N-1)(N-2)/6, am I correct?

Comment: This helped me a lot with a code challenge at work, thanks! Also, this calculates it for you as a shortcut: https://www.hackmath.net/en/calculator/n-choose-k?n=7&k=3&order=0&repeat=0

Answer (score 2):

The number of triangles that can be formed given N non collinear points is 
n = N(N-1)(N-2) / 6