# How many triangles can be formed if the vertices are chosen from a set of n points all lying on a circle?

Tags: combinations

I couldn't understand the question.Why the points must lie on the circle?Is the answer C(n,3)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many triangles can be formed from N points on a circle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206762/how-many-triangles-can-be-formed-from-n-points-on-a-circle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the points all lie on a circle, no three of them can be collinear
with each other.
That means you don't have to worry about whether three points on the same
line can be said to define a "triangle".

Your answer is correct.